# Can I scale an image to go beyond the box it is bound by?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an`<img>` to resize dynamically. Sometimes I need that image to go beyond the box it is bound by, but it seems to stop and distort. Can this be done?

```
<div>
 <img src='smjpg.jpg' />
</div>

div{
  width: 20px;
}
img{
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: yes, although I am not sure it warrants a downvote. The intent was pretty clear.

Comment: I have to say, not too sure why it was downvoted. It certainly wasn't me ;)

Comment: I suspected as much. A silent SO assassin.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I would, mostly because the code you supplied. Works. That's due to the CSS box model. Parents are stretched to fit children... I don't honestly understand your question, that why I'm inclined to downvote.

Comment: Hmm, I am using foundation, could that be the issue?

Comment: How's about you post relevant code that actually has the problem you are trying to fix... Start from there. As for your question, yes it can be done.

Comment: Please provide your code which has issues, or a snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

Just use CSS for the bounding `div`.

```
#imgDiv {
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: @MildFuzz make sure you have set the perpendicular length, I am assuming height, to auto.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the parent container to grow for other elements, with no fixed size, then consider using the `float` property or `position: absolute` on the child element. Absolute positioning removes the child from the flow of the page, so the parent container will see nothing to expand around. Floating has a similar visual effect, provided overflow is visible and no clearfix is used, but the child does affect the layout of its siblings. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lpd_/rd4HP/3/ (try adjusting the result width).